# A parameter showing how oval the system of vectors is.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I am modelling ionospheric currents for my master's thesis. The currents that I have simulated must take a form of two vortices (one counterclockwise, another one clockwise). I simulated them in the form of equivalent vectors (I have several magnetic observatories, and local time in hours; so, in each of these points I have an equivalent vector).

The matter is that the shape of these currents depends on the season: in winter the current system disintegrates, while in summer it can be seen really well. A disintegrated system does not have an oval shape (for example, during J-season), while during summer it is more oval than during other seasons.
**I need to create a parameter showing, in fact, how oval the current vortex is.** Please give me any idea how to do that, as I am really losing my mind with this. I have thought of it for a long time, and I tried to summarize all the vector's angles, but it doesn't have seasonal dependence...

Please, help me to find a solution... *This new parameter could really save my thesis...*

I attach the pictures of these currents. In the first pic, during J-season it is disintegrated, while during others it is Ok. In the second pic, in the top left (winter) subplot it is disintegrated, while in the bottom left (summer) it is the most integrated. In the second picture seasonal dependence is much better seen. The two right subplots are for autumn and spring, so there the currents are more integrated than in winter, but less than in summer.

[image]

[image]